# PHP Timeslot dynamic listing issue

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am slightly confused to build Time-slot logic dynamically could you please help me out.
I need to display some list of time-slot but each time slot will be of two hour. please see list inline below

```
00:00 02:00
02 04
04 06
06 08
08 10
10 12
12 14
14 16
16 18
18 20
20 22
22 00
```

Code

```
public function getTimeSlot(){

    $custom = array();
    $M      = 'AM';

    for($i=0;$i<=23;$i++):
        $time1 = strtotime($i.':00:00');
        $time2 = strtotime(($i*2).':00:00');
        $diff = $time2 - $time1;
        $custom[] = date('H:i:s ', $diff);
    endfor; 

    pr($custom);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: This is my project requirement and i need to this code of multiple time in different places of file. I wont able to choose static approach that why i posted this query in stack-overflow @cornelb

Comment: Requirement of project unable to define here due to some restrictions. It make sense because i have a drop down and it take these type of values.. use has a option to select a slot and move onward as per requirement concern

Comment: If you really want to more concern in this regard please text me via comment... Your concern it will highly appreciated for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems vague. Is it like this?

```
00:00 02:00 
02:00 04:00 
04:00 06:00 
06:00 08:00 
08:00 10:00 
10:00 12:00 
12:00 14:00 
14:00 16:00 
16:00 18:00 
18:00 20:00 
20:00 22:00 
22:00 00:00
```

If I would just print a simple time, I would do something like:

```
$start = 0; $end = 22;
$time_slot = range($start, $end, 2);
$time_slot = array_map(function($time) use ($end){
    $next = ($time != $end) ? $time + 2 : 00;
    $times = array(sprintf("%02s:00", $time), sprintf("%02s:00", $next));
    return $times;
}, $time_slot);

foreach($time_slot as $time) {
    echo "$time[0] $time[1] <br/>";
}
```

Comment: I know my question is slightly unclear but as per my project concern i need to this @Ghost Thanks for understand my query and answer it